# PROBLEMS WITH RADCLIFFE THEME

Tags: css

To be honest I am a total beginner in css codes.
My page is https://visiapera.wordpress.com/ and I want to change the red color when selecting a title in navigation menu and make it white. Then, I have been trying to make the drop down menu to have black letters and white background, by having black lines between them. 
The only thing I have found and did something is that:

```
li:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

But still the red is there!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change backround of a menu link apply this css code

```
.main-menu > li:hover > a {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #000;
}
.main-menu ul a {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #000;
}
```

Use **[FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)** or built-in developer tools to easily find out which css code applies on different events.

Comment: but there is one more thing.... The selected title becomes totally white when the mouse is over. Is there anything I can do for that?

Comment: Is it possible to have the same white background in the drop down menu? And @Muhammet THANK YOU!